# notification call to IIS

Tags: .net, iis-8.5

I have a notification application, X company make some calles to my domain, last 2 weeks we lost those calls and I am trying to figure out if calls can reach to my IIS. their system supposed to retry every 15 min.

so how can I check if any calls to a specific URL taken in place?

I am using WebServiceHost to process notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the first place to look is in the IIS access log for the site.

Second, if you have a proxy between your webserver and X Company, you may be able to search those logs for their IP or the URL path.

Third, verify that the site is in fact accessible from the internet.